# Checkout code from subversion from URL on Oracle virtual machine

Tags: svn, virtual-machine

I am using an Oracle virtual machine which houses my SVN repository. The SVN server serves my repository using http://.

How do I download code from there to my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [download and install a Subversion client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients) on your local machine and use that to communicate with your server and [checkout a working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) of your codebase.

For Windows, I recommend [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) and for Linux I recommend [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/).

Finally, it would be worth your time to read the [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com).

Comment: Thank you, this works, But I want to transfer this code from windows  OS to Oracle virtual machine which runs Linux OS.

Comment: @Meambani do you mean transfer the _checkout_ of the code from the repository on your local machine, to the Oracle VM? Why not just install the client software as I mentioned above and do a checkout on the VM? If you want to be able to access the same checkout from your local machine and VM, then I would investigate how to create a network drive / shared folder pointing to your local checkout, on the VM.